# Types of NETEZZA Planners

Tags: netezza

What are the types of planners that we use in NETEZZA and what is their use?
Eg: FACTERAL_PLANNER

Can anyone explain or please provide any link to get to know about this.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [an unofficial blog post](http://blog.dintechno.com/2013/12/netezza-optimizer-parameters.html) that mentions:

- the Fact Relationship (factrel) planner,
- the Snowflake planner,
- the Star planner.

Here's a link to one document entitled [Determining fact relations with fact relation planner and Snowflake planner](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21570277) but the IBM website won't let me view it even after logging in with my customer id. You may have more luck. The title suggests that the factrel planner uses one algorithm (absolute table size) for guessing which are your fact tables while the snowflake planner uses a different method (size relative to other tables).

I can't find anything relevant about the snowflake planner or the star planner in any of the official documents or training documents I have. Searches for *snowflake* or *star* always return things about schemas rather than planners.